# Java Error when using clearform(); on a save button

Tags: java, user-interface

This is a Java Swing application to record CA results.The application will ask students to enter their Name, Student Number and CA Grade. The system must remember the Student 
with the highest and Lowest Grades and display them on the input screen. I am currently receiving an error when using the

```
clearForm();
```

when coding the save button on my GUI.Subsequently the clearform(); and listResults(); methods are giving me errors.

```
    private void saveBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    // Creating a temp Result
    result r = new result(nameTf.getText(), numTf.getText(), Integer.valueOf(resultTf.getText()));

    // Saving it to the object array
    registration[counter] = r;

    // Checking the high value currently being stored, if it is higher than the new score, update        
    if (Integer.valueOf(highNum.getText()) < Integer.valueOf(resultTf.getText())) {
        highNum.setText(resultTf.getText());
    }

    // Checking the low value currently being stored, if it is lower than the new score, update  
    if (Integer.valueOf(resultTf.getText()) < Integer.valueOf(lowNum.getText()) || counter == 0) {
        lowNum.setText(resultTf.getText());
    }

    clearForm(); // clear the three input boxes when the user presses save
    counter++;   // Increment the student counter
    listResults();  // List all stuudents currently stored in our object array
}
```

Asking this would be a lot easier with images.

Comment: "Cannot find symbol"

Comment: Well, the error will tell you the symbol that is not found and the line causing the problem, so make sure you define the symbol. We are not mind readers. We can't tell the problem based on the code you posted.

Comment: Either it can't find the methods called (bad imports or structuring of an internal class like ActionListener), you misspelled the name (Usually an IDE will catch this for you), or you are missing parameters when the methods are called.